# WalletConnect w/ react-native

Tags: walletconnect

Anybody used WalletConnect in react-native? How do you genreate a topic and key for the URI?

From the docs:

> Android has the easiest integration as it's operating system is designed to handle multiple applications subscribing to the same deep linking schema. Hence you will only need to register to the wc: schema that is defined per the WalletConnect URI standard.
> `# Example wc:00e46b69-d0cc-4b3e-b6a2-cee442f97188@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2Fbridge.walletconnect.org&key=91303dedf64285cbbaf9120f6e9d160a5c8aa3deb67017a3874cd272323f48ae`

Where is this link coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked around the WalletConnect Discord. The keys and topics are not generated. Deeplinking with this link should work.

**edit 2** Actually there is a subscription server. I recommend taking a look at this file to generate the qr code/deeplink

https://github.com/ShenaniganDApp/shenanigan-monorepo/blob/master/packages/app/src/connectWallet.ts